# What does the "RG" in coax cables mean?

Tags: cables

For instance RG-6, RG-58, RG-59 and RG-173? Also do the numbers have a specific meaning (like referring to a part of the specification)? Is there a document that lists all RG-* cables with their specifications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A series of standard types of coaxial cable were specified for military uses, in the form "RG-#" or "RG-#/U". They date from World War II and were listed in MIL-HDBK-216 published in 1962. These designations are now obsolete. The RG designation stands for Radio Guide;

From [The obvious place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable#Standards)

Comment: +1. Not for "red, gritty" after all, or radagast!

Comment: @Kaz I thought it stood for Round Ground. Since the outer conductor is normally round. And the Ground.

Comment: @Passerby no, you get that at the butcher shop.

Answer (score 1):

A simple wikipedia search gave this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RG-59

Usually even numbered cables (RG-58, RG-316 etc) have 50Ohm impedance and odd numbered have 75Ohm

Comment: ... like the 75-ohm [RG-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RG-6), which is widely used in the cable TV industry? Don't make sweeping generalizations when there's a really obvious counterexample.